# Dynamic image resolution in docker multi stage builds

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it possible to have a dynamic image resolution in docker for multistage builds?

The following works

```
ARG node_version=10-alpine

FROM node:${node_version} as stage1
```

but the following

```
FROM ubuntu as dbdump

ARG node_version=10-alpine

FROM node:${node_version} as stage1
```

fails with the error

```
Dockerfile:5
--------------------
   3 |     ARG node_version=10-alpine
   4 |
   5 | >>> FROM node:${node_version} as stage1
   6 |
   7 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to parse stage name "node:": invalid reference format
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `ARG`s that get used in `FROM` lines need to be declared before the very first `FROM` line.  Anything that's after a `FROM` line is specific to that build stage.

```
ARG node_version=10-alpine

FROM ubuntu as dbdump
...

FROM node:${node_version} as stage1
...
```